# Failed HDD HP server Raid 5

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hp-proliant

I have some problem with my server HP proliant , currently raid 5 is running 6 HD each 146gb  and 1 hd is error. That i difflicult to find same model spare type.
So can i replace our harrdisk with different model or size? And is can be running normally?

Thanks
Faishol

Comment: Can you, yes, should you, probably not - a 300GB disk will work but you should try to find another 146GB if possible. Where are you in the world? I may have spares - I'd need to know the part number of the ones you already have.

Comment: Thank you for great answer, Im in ID, is a HDD i know on amazon and ebay that they sell.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a different HDD but the extra space - if any - will not be used.
Clearly be sure that the new HDD is bigger than the old one.

Comment: Thank you, is possible directly replace  my hd when os running, since HD support hot plug.

Comment: If HD support hot plug yes, no problem. Please remember to vote or accept the answer if you find it useful.

Comment: Ok let me try first waiting new hdd come

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you find the same part?

Find the spare part number listed on the drive and Google it. Select a retailer of your choice and order the drive.

Comment: Thank you, i have find the same spare type, in amazon and ebay that have a same spare type,but take a long time for deliver.

Comment: Is possible directly replace when server running? Since HDD support hot swap plug

Comment: Yes, it is possible.